# make a header full screen (width) css

Tags: css

I am trying to extend my header to cover the full page. http://dev.webgrowth.biz/ and I want it look like this one http://www.webgrowth.biz/ I have been trying everything for hours now. any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

You can achieve the effect using a container element, then just set the containing elements margin to `0 auto` and it will be centered.

**Markup**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContent">
        Header text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header{
    width:100%; 
    background: url(yourimage);
}
#headerContent{
    margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;
}
```

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ececec;
}

#headerContent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="headerContent">
        Header text
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Live Demo]**
[Live Demo]:http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/cqnUW/

Answer (score 8):

Just set the header width to be 100vw to make it full screen width 
and set the header height to be 100vh to make it full screen height

Answer (score 5):

```
#header {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
background: xxxx;
}

#header #content {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 800px; /* or whatever */
}

<div id="header">
<div id="content">
stuff here
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to make the header full screen is set height to be 100vh

```
#header{
height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `max-width:1250px;` that is currently on your body on your #container. This way your header will be 100% of his parent (body) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

Comment: This answer is really light. It would be nice to give some explanations...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `max-width` from the `body`, and put it to the `#container`.

So, instead of:

```
body {
    max-width:1250px;
}
```

You should have:

```
#container {
    max-width:1250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the body max-width:110%;
and the make the width on the header 110% it will leave a small margin on left that you can fiX with margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -10px;

Answer (score -1):

just do

```
#RandomDiv{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">My Dashboard</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="learn">Learn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="teach">Teach</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="Mylibrary">My Library</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Likes</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="Pics">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="audio">Audio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="Videos">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
    <li><a href="#">Views</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">account</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="SI">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="Reg">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="Deactivate">Deactivate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Uploads</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="Pics">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="audio">Audio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="Videos">Videos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="Add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Documents</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="Add">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="delete">Download</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
body{
    max-width:110%;
    margin-left:0;
}
.menu {
    height: 40px;
    width:110%;
    margin-left:-4px;
    margin-top:-10px;

    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }
.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;
    background: #1f2024;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ELvbq/)

try also resizing the browser tab to see it in action